# Replacing the jQuery .on() method in Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m trying to replace my jQuery with Vanilla Javascript but I’m not able to replicate jQuery’s `.on()` method for this script ...

```
document.querySelectorAll( "nav.subpage button" ).forEach( node => {

    node.addEventListener( "click", function() {

        this.closest( "nav.subpage" ).querySelectorAll( ".current" ).forEach( node => {

            node.classList.remove( "current" );

        });

        this.closest( "div" ).querySelectorAll( ".wrapper" ).forEach( node => {

            node.style.display = "none";

        });

        // =/= c l o s e - b u t t o n

        if ( !this.classList.contains( "close" ) ) {

            this.classList.add( "current" );

            document.getElementById( this.dataset.target ).style.display = "block";

        }

    });

});
```

I need it to make this script work on dynamically added content, too.

Please help!

Comment: What jQuery code are you trying to rewrite? Which part is failing? What does the html look like?

Comment: For dynamically added content, what you need to use is event listener delegates - google that

Comment: Thanks @Kinglish, that was actually what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I figured it out ...

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
console.log(e.target);
if (e.target.matches('nav.subpage button')) {
    e.target.closest('nav.subpage').querySelectorAll('.current').forEach(node => {
        node.classList.remove('current');
    });
    e.target.closest('div').querySelectorAll('.wrapper').forEach(node => {
        node.style.display = 'none';
    });
    // close - button
    if (!e.target.classList.contains('.close')) {
        e.target.classList.add('current');
        document.getElementById(e.target.dataset.ref).style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

});

This page was quite helpful: https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate.